# Deducing distance of closest neighbor galaxy from expression of correlation and mean galaxy density

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, distances, galaxy-cluster

The original post was on physics exchange but I prefer to move it here :

I am trying to estimate the distance of closest galaxy neighbor knowing the expression of number of neighbors $\text{d}N$ into a volume $\text{d}V$, the mean density $n_\text{gal}$ and the correlation function, i.e with this expression:

$$\text{d}N=n_{\text{gal}}\,\text{d}V\,(1+\xi(r))$$

with $\xi(r)=\bigg(\dfrac{r}{r_{0}}\bigg)^{-\gamma}\quad\text{with}\quad\gamma\,\sim\,1.77 \quad\text{and}\,r_{0}\,\sim\,5\,\text{Mpc}$.

I must precise that expression of $\xi(r)$ is valid for $r$ between $0.5\,\text{and}\,10\,\text{Mpc}$

I take into my calculation the following value for $n_{\text{gal}}=0.0420\,\text{h}^{-3}\,\text{Mpc}^{-3}$ : I tried to choose a typical value for this density but it depends on which scale we consider (galaxy cluster, super cluster, very large scales ...), so maybe don't focus on this value.

What it interests me is to have elements to answer to the following question :
**How could I infer the distance of the closest galaxy from us?**

**UPDATE 1:** Maybe I should take the lower limit of validity for the definition of $\xi(r)$, i.e $r=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$ and so:

$$\text{d}N/\text{d}V=n_{\text{gal}}\,(1+\xi(r=0.5))$$

So I would have:

$$\text{D}_{\text{closest}}=\bigg(n_{\text{gal}}(1+(0.5/5)^{-1.77})\bigg)^{-1/3}=0.7353\,\text{Mpc}$$

But by taking $r=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$, I am already located myself like the closest neighbor was at $r=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$, am I not ?

Is this reasoning correct?

Any help is welcome

Comment: Yes I would say is a circle. ...

Comment: @Alchimista . Do you think this is the right method ? As I said, But by taking $r=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$, I am already located myself like the closest neighbor was at $r=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$, am I not ? this would be an issue, no ?

Comment: No I am saying that it seems that you impose the result to be that.... I have the same doubt that you have.

Comment: But it somehow correct that if there is a parameter that holds between, say 0.5 and 10, something should be found int between. But indeed one could have chosen every value in that range perhaps. I don't know much about correlation. I would naively work without it once I know the total number of galaxies in a sphere of radius 10 Mpc.

Comment: Sorry that I can only comment. In my mind the corf funct account for dishomogeneity at various scales. Once you identify a range you know the average number of objects around. From that you consider them homogeneously distributed in a sphere (or a cube for that it matters) and infer the distance between two neighbours. One is you and the second the closest galaxy.

Comment: What the representation of r here and distance ? Are they same ?

Comment: @Reign .I think that $r$ reresents the physical distance and $\text{D}_{\text{closest}}$ is the mean distatnce of closest between objects like galaxies. I make confusions between both distances since if I chose the lower value $r_{0}=0.5\,\text{Mpc}$, I am already located mylself at the closest neighbour, am I not ? What do you think about it ? regards

Comment: I think r might represent the distance from us to some radius that we are taking as a volume. But from here mean distance definition just makes not much sense..

Comment: I understand your concern but I dont know the answer for that sorry.